# Can I use AssetManager returned by Context from other threads?

Tags: android

I'm building my own 2D game engine. I'm implementing a game view that bases `GLSurfaceView`, so I'm also implementing its `Renderer` class. The documents say that the interface is used by a separate thread ("GLThread" according to the stack trace). I think I can handle pretty much everything concurrently by putting locks and using handler except... asset loading.

I'm not sure if I can use the instance of `AssetManager` returned by `Context.getAssets()` on GL thread. No one, even no documentation says it could be used from another thread(other than main thread). I even wrote a test that uses one instance of AsssetManager from multiple threads.

- Can I use `AssetManager` returned by `Context.getAssets()` from another thread? (assuming that it will be used by only one thread at a time and not be used after `onDestroy()` call)

Judging by the fact that `Context.getAssets()` returns the same instance every call, it seems that it merely returns the internal member. But I don't know if this means I should put a lock around it.

**Extra bits**

I tried to come up with this "Resource request" channel between GL thread and main thread using a `Handler` and `FutureTask`s. However, I found that there's no way to sync those two threads by any means I can think of. There's this case where the activity is running `onDestroy()` and GL thread is waiting for the main thread to return the resources(`InputStream` opened by `AssetManager.open()` from the main thread) in FutureTask on `onSurfaceCreated()`. There's literally no way to sync when this is happening. The activity just waits for the GL thread to return to the message pump, so it can get stuck forever before OS kills the app.

The GL thread could load assets one by one over multiple handler messages, but that's just a waste of CPU time. I want to load all the assets on the `onSurfaceCreated()` callback. Sharing `AssetManager` seems to be the only best option here if possible.

Comment: The test didn't die, btw. It just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `AssetManager` is in charge of Providing access to an application's raw asset files, naturally it would not be Threadsafe without some basic concurrency primitives like locks (which I believe are naturally implemented by the OS). Having the `AssetManager` load items on a separate thread would therefore not be an issue.

I personally make use of
`Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor()` to ensure work happens on a Background thread however, it is done sequentially to prevent any race conditions.
`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` should not be too much of an issue if performing read/writes on separate files concurrently.

The `Handler` threading primitive you mentioned can also work too